# How to handle same time request with Apache and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, apache2.4

Currently, we are facing a major problem in our project. We have the feature to block tickets of currently logged in users, Once the user allocates tickets by clicking action. On the click action, we are firing an ajax request and calculating ticket logic by the query. We have a large query that is running on AWS RDS.

For Example:

A user wants to book 4 tickets we have 5 steps for buying tickets. the steps go like this

> Step1: The user selects a date and show.
>
> Step2: A user enters number of tickets he needs (Once the user click
>   on this we put entered ticket into the  block table)
>
> Step3: Order details
>
> Step4: Address
>
> Step5: Payment

If payment success or fail in both cases we delete tickets from the block table so another user can buy.

Now the major problem happening on STEP2

> Scenario: Available tickets: 10   User A and User B request at the
>   same time.
>
> User A request for tickets = 6
>
> User B request for tickets = 5

This means the total requested tickets are more than available tickets

And this is working good. But when I tested to call the API Same time with multiple computers. It is allowing me to buy 11 Tickets Which is more than 10 Tickets.

It happens only when we call requests at the same time. If there is a difference of seconds, It works fine.

What we are using for that:

> Server: Apache 2.4.18
>
> Language: PHP7.0
>
> Database:  Mysql (AWS RDS)

I am also sharing my source code to have an idea of what exactly I am doing.

```
 $res = $this->db->query("SELECT IFNULL(sum(tb.tickets),0) as total_blocked,
                                     ttb.tickets as totalUserBlock,
                                     e.max_tickets,IFNULL(awm.tickets,0) as user_allowed_tickets,
                                     IFNULL(SUM(me.tickets),0) as paid_tickets,
                                     IFNULL(sum(me.free_tickets),0)  as freetix,
                                     s.tickets as alocated_tickets,
                                     s.purchased as tickets_purchased,
                                     s.start_date,s.start_time
                                     FROM schedule s
                                     left JOIN event e on e.id=s.event_id
                                     left JOIN myevent me on me.schedule=s.id AND me.uid = '" . $this->user_id . "'
                                     left JOIN ticket_blocked ttb ON ttb.sch_id=s.id  AND ttb.user_id = '" . $this->user_id . "' AND ttb.status = 1
                                     left JOIN ticket_blocked tb ON tb.sch_id=s.id AND tb.status = 1

                                     left JOIN allowmore awm on awm.schedule=s.id AND awm.uid = '" . $this->user_id . "'
                                     WHERE s.id='" . $id . "' ")->row_array();

        $res['remote']=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];                                                      
        $res['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT']=$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT'];                                                       
        file_put_contents('gourge.txt',json_encode($res,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT).PHP_EOL,FILE_APPEND);                                                         

        $total_purchased_tickets = $res['freetix'] + $res['paid_tickets'] + $res['totalUserBlock'];
        $limit = $res['user_allowed_tickets'] > 0 ? $res['user_allowed_tickets'] : $res['max_tickets'];
        $total_remain_tickets = ($res['alocated_tickets']) - (($res['total_blocked'] + $res['tickets_purchased']));
        $limit = $limit - $total_purchased_tickets;


        if ($limit > $total_remain_tickets) {
            $tickets = $total_remain_tickets;
        } else {
            $tickets = $limit;
        }

        $tickets = $total_remain_tickets > $limit ? $total_remain_tickets : $limit;
        /*checking if user is allowed for the next step
        true => Allowed to book
        false => Not allowed
        */
        if($post['requested_tickets'] > $tickets){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
```

Sometimes the above code always return true.

Comment: What is $tickets_add?

Comment: @UrsolSolutions  $tickets_add removed. it was added for debug purposes.